# Add integers from 5 UITextFields to a UILabel in Cocoa Touch

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitextfield, uilabel

I'm trying to sum the integers from five `UITextFields` and post them to a `UILabel`.

This is the code I have tried, but it doesn't work properly. The number that shows up in the label is *not* the sum of my textfields. I have also tried to post to a textfield instead of a label, with the same result. No errors or warnings when I build.

```
int val = [textfield1.text intValue]
val = val+[textfield2.text intValue];
val = val+[textfield3.text intValue];
val = val+[textfield4.text intValue];
val = val+[textfield5.text intValue];

NSString *labelStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i", val];

label.text = labelStr;
```

Something wrong with the code? Alternative code? Grateful for all answers!

Comment: Duplicate of previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256356

Comment: Not a duplicate as the OP gives the code he is using the other was closed as not enough information

Comment: He posted the code in the previous question too (as a comment). He also seems to have ignored previous comments, e.g. that his terminology is confused, in that Xcode is the name of an IDE, not a programming language or framework.

Comment: The previous question was closed for not giving enough information. The questioner has re-asked it with more information, and now you want to close it again? How is he (I'm using this gender-neutrally) supposed to get a solution to his problem from us if he can't receive answers on his original question and you won't let him post a new one?

Answer (score 0):

The code looks more or less right to me, aside from the memory leak. You should review [the memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html) and fix your leak.

My guess is that the numbers you entered add up to a number that is outside the range of an `int`. Entering, say, 1000000000 (10**9) in each of the five fields would be one way to pull this off, on any machine where an `int` is 32 bits (including, currently, the iPhone-OS devices).

Depending on the purpose of your app, you may be able to simply cap the five input fields; if the highest value that makes any sense is less than one-fifth (for five fields, and that's assuming they all have the same cap) of the maximum `int`, overflow is impossible.

If a cap won't solve the problem completely, try a different type. If the values should never be negative, use an unsigned type. Otherwise, try `long long`, or either of the floating-point types, or use NSDecimalNumber objects.

Of course, I could be completely wrong, since you didn't say what numbers you entered or what the result was. If it was zero, make sure that you hooked up your outlets in IB; if you forgot to do that, they contain `nil`, which, when you ask it for `text`, will return `nil`, which, when you ask it for an `intValue`, will return 0, and 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 = 0.